# Compaq ILO over SSH to Vmware - How to press ALT-F1

Tags: vmware-esx, ipmi, ilo, hp

I have a Compaq DL380 G4 running an ILO on a shared ethernet port, so I only have SSH access.  On this machine I have VMWare vSphere 4.  I can ssh into the ILO, issue remcons, and see the lovely VMWare management screen that offers to give me a management console if I was to issue the "alt-f1" command.

```
            VMware ESX 4.0.0 build-164009                                   

            HP ProLiant DL380 G4                                            

            2 x Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.40GHz                               
            10 GB Memory                                                    

    Download tools to manage this host from:                                

            http://192.168.1.118/                                           

    To open the ESX console, press Alt-F1.                                  
    To return to this screen, press Alt-F11.
```

However -- I can't seem to figure out how to issue an ALT-F1 over the SSH connection.  I found various resources that mention there is a hot key for alt, such as ESC key key (to send ALT-key), however I can't seem to find the magic key combination to send "ALT-F1" over SSH to this ILO.

Any thoughts?

[Table B-2 contains the Dell IPMI](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe2850/en/ug/t1390ab.htm) command mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that same Dell IPMI guide (which is different than others), F1 is ESC-O-P (shift, OP).

```
  ESC-ESC-SHIFT-OP-ESC-SHIFT-OP.
```

Gains access!

Answer (score 2):

iLO 2 has a hotkey configuration. You can just set up <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to be <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and use that key instead.